# how to view only 1 tab PAGE when clicking a menu item in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

I have a tab control with 2 tab pages and a menu strip with 2 items. when I click item 1 in menuStrip, I want to view ONLY TAB PAGE 1.

I tried

```
Private Sub item1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(...)
    TabPage2.Select()        
    TabPage2.Show()
    TabPage2.Visible = True
    TabPage1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be under `TabControl`?

Comment: oh  am sorry !it is visual studio itself!

Comment: What do you mean it is Visual Studio itself?  Is this a macro?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TablControl`, following is feasible. [The fllowing post has alternative solutions as well.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/00dd3e0c-17b7-4375-a77a-dac752641beb/)

```
TabControl1.TabPages.RemoveByKey("Selection")
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.removebykey.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: i do not want to remove tab pages but view only 1 page as per the selected menu. 


  Consider i have a menu tool with 2 items edit and order! and a tab control with 2 tab pages - edit and -order

  `that is, if i select **edit** in menu, i want to open the edit tab in tab pages or view only the "EDIT TAB" and if i select **order** in menu, open order tab in tab collection pages`


**hope its not confusing**

Comment: @kiaara, Either you have to go with "PageEnabled" property or you need to Add/Remove TabPages at run time

Answer (score 0):

There is no any visible property for TABPAGES........... Instead of it you can use PageEnabled = True/False. Or you can remove the tabpages from tab control and add back.

You can do like this

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(YourSpecificTabPage)
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(YourSpecificTabPage)
```

Refer : [1. VB.Net Hide Tabpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055672/vb-net-hide-tabpage)
        [2. Programatically hide/remove tabpages in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740073/programatically-hide-remove-tabpages-in-vb-net)

Comment: but i want to view only a specific tab page from the collection as per the selected menu item

Comment: i did try this today sir but it keeps adding new tab each time you click!!

Comment: no i do not need to remove tab page, instead view a specific TAB PAGE based on the selection!!!

  But it is fine, i will try some other method!

Aniways thanks for the help!