# Hide Tab based on Active directory info

Tags: vb.net, active-directory

In Visual basic I want to be able to hide a tab based on whether the currently logged on users is in a certain group in Active directory.

I have already managed to link to active directory and pull back full name and phone number etc.

Not sure if this would be possible

Comment: This could help you [VB.Net Hide Tabpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055672/vb-net-hide-tabpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it

`If My.User.IsInRole("AD GROUP") Then
            despatchonly.Show()
        Else
            despatchonly.Hide()
        End If`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't too clear, but if I understand it correctly, it's pretty simple:

```
If IsInActiveGroup(Environment.UserName) 'or whatever username data you'd like...
    TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabYourTabName)
Else
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabYourTabName)
End If
```

---

`IsInActiveGroup` being some function you create to iterate through your list of users and see if he's in there. I'm not sure what data type you're storing the "active directory users" in.

Comment: Thanks I managed to do it this way in the end.

`If My.User.IsInRole("AD GROUP") Then
            despatchonly.Show()
        Else
            despatchonly.Hide()
        End If`